# Integrate Google drive with an stand alone desktop application

Tags: python, google-drive-api

Is there a way where I can make use of Google drive sdk to integrate drive functions with a desktop application [Python based]. It is not a web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. But since you haven't told us *what* you want to do, its going to be difficult giving you details. You can get started with [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJVCKvXtHtE) made by google developers.

Comment: I am making an application using which an user can edit a file and has an option to upload the file to his drive in a particular folder after proper authentication.

Comment: Editing and stuff like that will need to be handled by you. As for the google drive is only there for retrieving and saving files.

Comment: Ya editing is done locally in the system , the final saved file needs to be saved on the drive and can retrieved later by the application itself.
In picasa , there is a login option and we can upload files and retrieve them , I wanted something like that.